# Не могу записать массив данных в SDRAM из NIOS используя функция IOWR

Tags: c, память

Привет, всем! Не могу записать массива данных в память SDRAM из NIOS с помощью функции IOWR. Проблема заключается в том, что запись данных происходит нормально. Но после 452 итерации запись не происходит, не понимаю в чем проблема. Вроде адресное пространство для памяти начинается из 0x08000000 - 0x0bffffff и память 64 MB.

```
   for(i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    IOWR(DRAM_BASE + i, 0, i);
    printf("0x0%x\n", DRAM_BASE + i);
    }
```

Comment: 0. Какое отношение **IO** имеет к памяти? 1. Как объявлен `DRAM_BASE`?  Как объявлена `i`? 2. `printf("%p\n", ...);`

Comment: Привет. В NIOS насколько я понимаю есть функции макросы (IOWR, IORD, IOWR_32direct и т.д.), которые позволяют по адресу DRAM_BASE записывать данные в модули. В моем случае DRAM_BASE объявлен как #define DRAM_BASE 0x8000000. Не совсем понял вопрос "Как объявлена i", разве по циклу не видно?